# Node running unexisting version

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, version, nvm

When i try to install strapi in my Angular application I obtain this error:

```
You are running Node.js 14.20.0
Strapi requires Node.js >=16.0.0 <=20.x.x
Please make sure to use the right version of Node.
```

The problem is that I'm not using the v.14.20.0, If i run in the terminal `node-v` it shows `18.18.0`

Here what i tried and didn't work:

- switch version with nvm from `v14.20.0` to `v16.16.0` and delete `v.14.20.20`
- Delete nvm and all node files from my pc, reinstall only node `v.18.18.0`

Even If I've deleted all about nvm and node and reinstalled only node `v.18.18.0` the error ragarding v14.20.0 persists..
It's strange, if i write `node -v` the terminal shows 18.18.0

**HINT**
The problem isn't Strapi, I obtain this error also performing other tasks that requires a node version higher than 14.20.0.

Thank you so much.

Comment: add your `package.json` file to the question.

Comment: Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

*FIXED*

I've fixed the problem deleting all the nvm and node files in my pc and reinstalling only node starting from scratch.

-Uninstall node and delete all folders
-Uninstall nvm and delete all folders
-Check for remaing cache file in (Windows):

C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local

Restart your pc

Install node.js